# include specific Pages to wp_list_pages with filter

Tags: filters, pages, widgets, wp-list-pages, include

How can i make a simple filter to display only specific pages (**include instead of exclude**) as an output to wordpress pages widget?

I made this code , but its not working

```
function specific_pages($output) {

$args = array(
    'include'  => array(147,12,32),
);
$output = get_posts($args);



return $output;
 }
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'specific_pages');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the corresponding hook would be https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_pages_args/

example code:

```
add_filter( 'widget_pages_args','include_special_pages' );
function include_special_pages( $args ) {
  $args['include'] = array( 147, 12, 32 );
  return $args;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. It is working!